# Who was George?

Tags: seitokai-yakuindomo

Most who watched Seitokai Yakuindomo probably remember the story of George, the heroic sailor who jumped off his ship in the middle of a storm to rescue a drowning cat. His story was heartwarming and fantastic, but also a bit bizarre since the character didn't appear anywhere prior.

Is George or his story a reference to anything? Or was this just a crazy story that wasn't making any particular reference?

[image]

Comment: I don't know about the sailor, but there is a maritime superstition that if a ship's cat fell or was thrown overboard, would bring a storm that would devastate/sink the ship, but if the ship were to somehow survive, it would have 9 years of bad luck.

Comment: @Krazer If you have a source for that, it would probably work as an answer. Doesn't explain everything but it does at least clear up some of the reference.

Comment: It's hard to cite a source for superstitions, but best I can find right now is [this source](http://boundforsouthaustralia.net.au/journey-content/pets-on-board.html) and [this source](http://playfulkitty.wordpress.com/2013/11/25/cats-in-history-the-ships-cat-mayflower-ii/)

Comment: Not sure if it's only me or the YouTube video got blocked for copyright infringement.

Comment: @AkiTanaka It is also blocked for me, so I've removed the link.